# sun java6 closure

Tags: java, closures

Does anybody knows how to use closure in sun java 6? I found this site http://www.javac.info/ but it looks like it only support open jdk right now.

Thanks,

Comment: (Java already has closures [fsvo], just not not a pretty method to create them -- anonymous inner classes will bind local *final variables* which can be used as *mutable refs*.)

Answer (score 1):

This guy says he has done it.  He put together a JAR file you import into your project:

http://llewellynfalco.blogspot.com/2010/09/lamdbas-in-java-16.html

Comment: That's not "BCGA" closures (pretty syntax). It shows how *final variables* can be bound to in the closure created by an anonymous inner class (and used as mutable ref's, but the author is not showing this there) -- in this case the author is taking advantage of the [double brace initialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization) syntax. It also looks like he provides some "function types" (classes) for `F1..Fn` -- in which case I'd recommend looking at [FunctionalJava](http://www.functionaljava.org/) as a more comprehensive package. However, +1 for the interesting link :P